# Add specific directory and its content to Universal target

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am switching from maven to sbt for a Scala project I am working on. I used to work with the maven assembly plugin where you can map any directory in the workspace to a target directory in the assembly. I didn't find any equivalent in sbt-native-package, it worth provide this feature for the Universe kind.

I understood that everything that is present in the universal subdirectory is copied to the package as such, and it works like a charm, but I lack something like the following snippet.

```
mappings in Universal += {
  directory("my/local/dir") -> "static/dirInPackage"
}
```

I would like to know if there is already a way to do that, in such case, I would be happy to know how to do it, and I propose my help to commit documentation for that part if you want.
If there is no way to do this kind of customization, I will be happy to propose a patch for that after having discussed specifications.

By the way, great job, your packager is working very well, thanks !

Comment: I don't know sbt-native-packager so...could copying the directory before packaging do the trick? Just probing before offering a final answer.

Comment: Hi Jacek, thanks for your comment. I will give it a try. It will be a quick fix for what I am doing at the moment, for sure. Anyway, I really think that this is a must have feature for sbt-native-packager in the long term.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After having discussed with the sbt-native-manager team and a first "rejected" pull request, here is the way to do this directory mapping in the build.sbt file (see pull request https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/pull/160 which provides mode detailed documentation) :

```
mappings in Universal <++= (packageBin in Compile, target ) map { (_, target) =>
    val dir = target / "scala-2.10" / "api"
    (dir.***) pair relativeTo(dir.getParentFile)
}
```

To reduce verbosity of the above snippet, there is an issue (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/161) to propose a more human readable way to express this directory mapping:

```
mappings in Universal ++= allFilesRelativeTo(file(target / "scala-2.10" / "api"))
```

Answer (score 6):

From https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager

If you'd like to add additional files to the installation dir, simply add them to the universal mappings:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager.Universal

mappings in Universal += {
 file("my/local/conffile") -> "conf/my.conf"
}
```

Comment: For the moment, it does not copy the content of the directory that way, only an empty directory is created ! I want to copy the directory AND its content recursively.

Comment: I have proposed a patch (pull request on github) to allow copying the content of a directory using the 'mappings' snippet above, will see if it will be merged: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/pull/159

Answer (score 6):

You could use a simple map on top of the directory method result.

==>  directory method documentation: [MappingsHelper.directory](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/latest/api/#com.typesafe.sbt.packager.MappingsHelper$)

For example:
// Packaging the content of `/src/main/resources` under `conf` add the following:

```
mappings in Universal ++= (directory("src/main/resources").map(t => (t._1, t._2.replace("resources", "conf"))))
```

Comment: I think there is typo it should be ... mappings in Universal ++= (directory("src/main/resources").map(t => (t._1, t._2.replace("resources", "conf"))))

Answer (score 0):

### This one seems to be the simplest example that worked for me

Takes all files in `res/scripts/` and puts it in the `bin/` directory when unzipped.

```
// In build.sbt
mappings in Universal <++= (packageBin in Compile) map { jar =>
  val scriptsDir = new java.io.File("res/scripts/")
  scriptsDir.listFiles.toSeq.map { f =>
    f -> ("bin/" + f.getName)
  }
}
```

If you choose a file that's not created, it will be created for you, for example `assets/` will make a new `assets` folder with the files. If you want files inside of this one using this approach you'll have to make a new `Seq` at least that's what I did. Here's my example

```
assets/
├── scripts
│   └── install_dependencies.sh
└── urbangrizzly.database
```

and the appropriate `build.sbt` section:

```
mappings in Universal <++= (packageBin in Compile) map { jar =>
    val assetsDir = new java.io.File("assets/")
    val scriptsDir = new java.io.File("assets/scripts")
    assetsDir.listFiles.toSeq.map { files =>
        files -> ("assets/" + files.getName)
    } ++ scriptsDir.listFiles.toSeq.map { files =>
        files -> ("assets/scripts/" + files.getName)
    }
}
```

If you need more, just keep using the `++` operator to concatenate the lists